# How to XOR two arrays of bytes in Python

Tags: python, arrays, byte, xor

I would like to perform an XOR between two arrays of bytes declared as:

```
a = bytes([0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08])
b = bytes([0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55])
```

I already tried `a ^ b`, but I've got the following error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'bytes' and 'bytes'

What is the most conscice way to perform the XOR operation?